# javascript code do not redirect to destinated part

Tags: javascript, html

my js code is not working

js code:

```
const signUpPageLink = document.querySelector('#signup-page-link');
const loginPageLink = document.querySelector('#login-page-link');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

signUpPageLink.addEventListener('click',function(){
    wrapper.style.top = '-100%';
})

loginPageLink.addEventListener('click',function(){
    wrapper.style.top = '0%';
})
```

it should go to a "register" part.
it just dont work! i dont know more what to do, i really need help.

Tried so many ways but it didnt worked

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your code seems to add click event that change the style. If you want it to link for some page you can simply use anchor. Please edit your question and add more code so we can help.

Comment: loginPageLink.addEventListener('click',function(){
    location.href = 'my-registration-page.html' ;
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
signUpPageLink.addEventListener('click',function(){
    wrapper.style.top = '-100%';
    location.replace("https://www.example.com/register")
})
```

Or:

```
signUpPageLink.addEventListener('click',function(){
    wrapper.style.top = '-100%';
    location.href("https://www.example.com/register")
})
```